# Is it possible to send keys to a computer via USB?

Tags: usb, usb-power, keyboard

- Is it possible to send keys to a computer connecting the RPi A+ via USB on the computer?
- Will the RPi have enough power?
- If yes, how?

Comment: google is your friend - [head over to adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/overview) and [especially the modules section](https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget?view=all#other-modules)  --  this is for a pi zero, but I guess you could make it work with any

Comment: Keys? You mean keybaord strokes? When you say USB, you mean using the USB protocol or a USB pen drive? Is yes, then you can use the PS2 emulation over USB to send keystrokes... but that is hardware dependend. You cannot just connect to USB like old day serial console. Even though USB stands for Universal Serial Bus.... doh

Comment: Please edit your question so that it's at least clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partly no.

Based on what I inferred<sub>(guessed)</sub> from your question, no. Plugging in the Pi to a computer via USB using the micro-USB port will not provide you the chance to send data over it since, from what I've guessed, you're trying to use the Pi's micro-USB port. That port is strictly for power only except on the Pi Zero, one is for data and one is for power. Nevertheless, all Pis can only work as a host (you cannot plug it into a USB port and use it as a device or "slave").

You'll need adapters like a USB to serial adapter and some programming skills to pull it off. So, yes.

Comment: There's no mention in the question or any of the subsequent comments of a micro USB port. Kinda funny seeing it in a potential answer?

Comment: @goobering "based on what I inferred". This is a common question where people ask if it's possible to connect their Pi via USB and use it as a slave.

Comment: @goobering But he's entirely right. It's the answer I expected ;)

Comment: @goobering Sometimes you just gotta take a guess.